# UITableView of iOS SDK 6.1 don't compatible with iOS SDK 5.1

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5.1, ios6.1

I have created `UITableView` project in XCode 4.6 with iOS 6.1 SDK, and set target sdk to 5.1, when the app calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, the app throw a exception, the simulator is 5.1, on simulator 6.x is ok.

1:
`[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance

2:Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: `-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Paste more code of cellForRowAtIndexPath..

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath this function is added in ios6.0 so you cant run app with this code in ios5

Comment: it is my mistake. I should use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier without forIndexPath in 5.x and use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: in 6.x and later if it is need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Apple documentation, you'll see that [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a) came in with iOS 6.0.

That means if you try to call this method on iOS 5.X devices, it's going to throw an exception.

It would be better if you used the older ["`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3a) call if possible.

One big difference between the two calls is that the latter (older) one *can* return nil, in which case you need to alloc/init a new reuseable cell.

Answer (score 6):

**1. dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier**
**Availability**
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
**->** Minimum iOS version required to run this function is **iOS 2.0**

**2 .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:**
**Availability**
Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
**->** Minimum iOS version required to run this function is **iOS 6.0**

**EDIT**
IF your want to use this function the you can check your current device version and then implement this

```
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
NSLog(@"curr version = %f",[currSysVer floatValue]);

if ([currSysVer floatValue] >= 6) {
    //iOS 6.0 and later code
    // dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
}
else{
    //dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier
}
```

Comment: thank you, I should use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier without forIndexPath parameter.