# UIView Animation not working in ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6, ios5.1

I have a `UITableView`. I want to make animation when cell is loading in table. I make it like this.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect tmpFrame;
    CGRect originalFrame;
    originalFrame = cell.frame;
    tmpFrame = cell.frame;
    tmpFrame = CGRectMake(0, -50, 320, 50);
    cell.frame = tmpFrame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
    cell.frame = originalFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This code is working fine in iOS 6 (iPhone simulator 6) but it's not working in iOS 5.1 (iPhone simulator 5.1).

Comment: follow this link buddy.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727380/uitableview-of-ios-sdk-6-1-dont-compatible-with-ios-sdk-5-1/14727833#14727833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.
i put this code into

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

before return cell.

Answer (score 0):

So I know you already have the solution, but I might recommend using the animation blocks unless you are making it compatible with older versions. Anyway if you are not this might offer a different way to write animations. I like doing it this way because I feel like I have more control over whats happening and less mess.

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if(!cell){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
}

CGRect movementFrame = cell.frame; // set the movement frame for modification
movementFrame.origin.y -= 50; //adjust only one variable instead of making a rect..

//Start your animation block. 
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     //Animation here
                     cell.frame = movementFrame; // Commit your changes basically
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //Completeion c

                 }];
```

So awesome! Take Care ^^

*Edit*

Went to test it, and realized I left out a crucial part. I apologize.. but this code does work and will do this animation its kind of interesting on a grouped table with a page full of sections.